Spotipy in Docker environment without opening broswer and not using flask
I have a Python script that uses the Spotipy library to get the currently playing track from Spotify and send it to a server. I'm trying to run this script in a Docker container, but Spotipy attempts to open a browser for authentication, which is not possible in a headless Docker environment. Additionally, when I start the Docker container, I don't get any output in the console, and nothing happens. I also want to avoid using Flask.
import datetime
import json
import os
import time

import requests
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

LAST_REFRESH = None

def refresh_access_token():
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(
        auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
            client_id="<foo>",
            client_secret="<foo>",
            redirect_uri="http://localhost:8888",
            scope="user-read-currently-playing",
        )
    )

    current_user = sp.current_user()

    assert current_user is not None

    with open(".cache", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    access_token = data["access_token"]

    os.remove(".cache")

    global LAST_REFRESH
    LAST_REFRESH = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("Access token refreshed")

    return access_token


def get_current_track(access_token):
    try:
        response = requests.get(
            'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
            headers={
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
            }
        )
        json_resp = response.json()

        track_id = json_resp['item']['id']
        track_name = json_resp['item']['name']
        artists = [artist for artist in json_resp['item']['artists']]

        link = json_resp['item']['external_urls']['spotify']

        artist_names = ', '.join([artist['name'] for artist in artists])

        current_track_info = {
            "id": track_id,
            "track_name": track_name,
            "artists": artist_names,
            "link": link
        }

        return current_track_info
    except:
        print('Error: Unable to get current track')
        time.sleep(10)


def send_to_server(spotifyID):
    print(spotifyID)
    #...


def main():
    current_track_id = None
    access_token = refresh_access_token()
    while True:
        try:
            if (datetime.datetime.now() - LAST_REFRESH).seconds > 3500:
                access_token = refresh_access_token()

            current_track_info = get_current_track(access_token)

            if current_track_info['id'] != current_track_id:
                current_track_id = current_track_info['id']
                send_to_server(current_track_id)

            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            print('Error: Unable to get current track')
            time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


This is my dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]

And this is my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.1'

services:
  test:
    image: test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: test

How can I run this Spotipy script in Docker without requiring browser interaction for authentication, and ensure that I get console output from the container?

Get Recently Played Tracks required "OAuth 2.0"(Authorization code flow). It means you have to log in step by Browser at least once. No way to get a access token without opening the browser.

Does that mean it's not possible to run the whole thing in docker?

Docker can’t skip Lon in step, docker or none docker do not matter.

That means I can't just run it on a Linux server without a user interface. Is there no other way to automate this?

Yes are right the authorization code flow have to use UI.  If you use Client Credentials Flow can use automation but it is limited functionality. it means Get Recently Played Tracks can't use by client credentials flow. Those comparison table in here

Ok, too bad, then I'll try something else. Thanks anyway

You can copy the .cache file from your pc to the docker container.

But I would have to do this once an hour because the access token expires. It should also work when the PC is not on and it can simply run on a server.
